# Neo4j, Cypher: Conditional Create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a specific problem to make a conditional create statement. I can't use `MERGE` here since the `MATCH` AND `CREATE` statement are different. Here is the query..

```
....
WITH m
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[r1:FeedNext{user_id:USER_ID}]->(m)-[r2:FeedNext{user_id:USER_ID}]->(y) 
WHERE x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL 
WITH x, y, m, r1, r2
CREATE (x)-[:FeedNext{user_id:USER_ID}]->(y) 
DELETE r1, r2 
RETURN m
```

returns 0 rows For the case when `x` and `y` are `null`.

While `m` is not returned  `null` for the same case on running..

```
....
WITH m
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[r1:FeedNext{user_id:USER_ID}]->(m)-[r2:FeedNext{user_id:USER_ID}]->(y) 
RETURN m
```

What's the way around, to return the value of `m` in all cases?

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean that for your second query, `x` and `y` are null, but `m` is not? Could you show it in a [console](http://console.neo4j.org)?

Comment: In general, your `WHERE` condition limits `CREATE` by making sure it´s never reached if `x` and `y` are `NULL`, but then the `RETURN` clause is not reached either. If you want to return whether or not you create you have to filter only the `CREATE` clause, for instance doing the creating within `FOREACH` with a collection that is empty in one case and contains `x,y` in another case.

Comment: @jjaderberg Yes, exactly. Actually `m` is the input in this query from a query before this one, which I missed to mention(sorry for that). I am updating this in the question..

Comment: Gotcha. I can share one technique you can try, it is a bit roundabout, maybe someone else can suggest something better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition limits `CREATE` by making sure it´s never reached if `x` and `y` are `NULL`, but then the `RETURN` clause is not reached either. If you want to return whether or not you create you have to filter only the `CREATE` clause. One way to do so is by creating and deleting within a `FOREACH` clause. The `FOREACH` clause takes a collection, and you can do your filtering by letting the collection be empty in the one case and contain `x,y` in the other case. With nested `FOREACH` you can do that like so

```
....
WITH m
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[r1:FeedNext {user_id:{USER_ID}}]->(m)-[r2:FeedNext {user_id:{USER_ID}}]->(y)
FOREACH (a IN CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [x] END | 
    FOREACH (b IN CASE WHEN y IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [y] END | 
        CREATE a-[:FeedNext { user_id:{USER_ID}}]->b
        DELETE r1, r2
    )
)
RETURN m
```

Comment: I just tried this query, but it's giving the following error `Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure` and on trying `CREATE UNIQUE` it throws `expecting 'a' to be be node but it's a null`

Comment: It works for me. Here is a console http://console.neo4j.org/r/bjotdo Do `MATCH (m{uid:"m"})` to get `m`, then paste my query and replace the `{USER_ID}` parameter with `1`.

Comment: I just tried on the console too. It throws `Error: java.lang.NullPointerException` when r1 and r2 doesn't exist. This is the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XvzrkA012sLXNTVnctTEVwcWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You're right, I had a brain fart. Coalesce doesn't return an empty collection but the first non-null value or null if there is none, so it only works when `x` and `y` are not null. The principle is correct, however, and I updated my answer to use `CASE` to get the empty collection. Wanna give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to match based on condition, this is a workaround which I used. Hope it helps.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH b2p = (x1)-[r1:FeedNext {user_id:{USER_ID}}]->(m1)
OPTIONAL MATCH b2c = (x2)-[r2:FeedNext {email_id:{EMAIL_ID}}]->(m2)
FOREACH (usertype IN CASE WHEN {USER_TYPE} = 'B2P' AND b2p is not null THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE x1-[:ORDER]->(or:Order{order_id:{ORDER_ID}}))
FOREACH (usertype IN CASE WHEN {USER_TYPE} = 'B2C' AND b2c is not null THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE x2-[:ORDER]->(or:Order{order_id:{ORDER_ID}}))
```

Here {USER_TYPE} is an input parameter which is conditional to choose either of the merge paths.

Thanks